# How to create test suite for any broken images using machine learning based algoritham/ AI based Automation

Tags: selenium, machine-learning, cypress, webdriver-io

I am working on a sizeable large eCommerce web-portal where, there are many images on thousands of CMS generated dynamic pages.
The location of the image on page is fixed.

How to create a Javascript / Machine Learning based test automation bot, which will skim through all of these pages & result in the pages where images do not load.

Time for this test run is not a constraint, as we won't be putting this run as CI/CD pipeline, rater a standard overnight run.

Comment: What do you mean by "images do not load"? They are failed to be downloaded from the server? Or the image does not correspond to the context?

Comment: On Amazon S3  image-crawler service lists the content of the s3 bucket containing the images, the existing folders inside the bucket are also included in the list. But I would like to separate the cause of issue from the check as in future images may not load due to some other reason / they might be missing alltogether

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Start by fetching a page (load it in a browser, or make a HTTP request for it, depending if you need to wait for JS or not)
2 Find all  tags, and store each one in a Set of toVisitPages
3 Find all  tags on current page
4 For each  tag on current page, make a HTTP request to it, does it 404? If so - add it to your broken list
5 Start at step 2) with the next page from toVisitPages